# RewriteRule how to atoms RewriteCond's variables

Tags: regex, mod-rewrite

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+).example.com$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^$ server.php?m=channel&a=index&dir=%1 [L]
RewriteRule ^index(_([0-9]*))?.html$ server.php?m=channel&a=preview&dir=%1&page=$2 [L]
```

dir=%1 in first RewriteRule is work, and in the second RewriteRule does not work. I want to know how to slove this problem?

Comment: It is likely that you should double the `RewriteCond` before the second RewriteRule. [RewriteCond directives only apply to the RewriteRule that immediately follows them.](http://serverfault.com/questions/398587/multiple-rewritecond-doesnt-work)